# Data-structure with TTL

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I want to build key-value storage with such properties:

- O(log N) insertion complexity and write optimized;
- Faster insertion for sequential writes (keys are in sequential order with gaps);
- O(log N) key-lookup complexity;
- O(log N + M) key-range query complexity;
- o(N) outdated key eviction complexity;
- All keys have timestamp associated with them, old items periodically evicted;
- Key eviction must be done explicitly by calling some function or method;
- If key is outdated it is still can be read;
- Key eviction doesn't need to be very precise;

So the interface can look like this:

```
template<class K, class V>
class Index {
    ...
    class iterator_pair...
    ...
    Index(int TTL);
    void insert(K key, V value);
    V find(K key);
    iterator_pair<K, V> get_range(K begin, K end);
    void remove_outdated();
};
```

How such data-structure can be implemented?

**Update**

So far so good I decided to use TSB-tree (time split b+ tree) to implement this. It is almost perfect fit - writes and key lookups has logarithmic complexity; it is write optimized (most inserts are just writes to pre-allocated memory buffer, allocations are amortized by many inserts); old key eviction can be done by removing historical nodes and this nodes can be easily tagged for fast access, even more - key eviction can be done during node splits.

RB-tree based solution is pretty valid too, maybe I use it instead of TSB-tree because of ease of implementation (compared to TSB-tree).

Comment: O(N log N) is a pretty loose bound for range queries. I mean, even an unsorted array will give you O(N). Did you mean O(log N + M), where M is the number of elements actually within the range?

Comment: This looks very much like C++ - do you wantto add that tag?
Also, is key your timestamp, or is eviction based on something else?

Comment: Key and timestamp is a different things. Timestamp must be generated internally when new key-value pair added to the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a red-black tree (possibly of contiguous key-value arrays, to satisfy your second requirement), overlaid with a linked list of insertion order. (If you don't necessarily insert keys ascending order by timestamp, make this a fibonacci heap instead of a linked list.)

Incidentally, I'm assuming by your penultimate point that you mean "it is not an error to attempt to look up a key which refers to an expired item".

Comment: "it is not an error to attempt to look up a key which refers to an expired item" - right, in a case when this item doesn't removed from set by key-eviction procedure.

Comment: +1. Absent the range query requirement, a dictionary or hash map (combined with the linked list) would work.

Comment: I don't completely understand how to optimize rb-trees for write. Can you clarify this?

Comment: They're already optimal -- insertion is O(log n). Is there something else you mean by "write optimized"?

Comment: By write optimization I mean ability to index large amount of inserts, even by the cost of more slow reads. For example in some b+tree implementations, items appended to some leaf buffer in insertion order without sorting. Read performance is sacrificed (impossible to use binary search on node data) for write performance.

Comment: Such optimizations are generally best left alone until after you've got an initial implementation done so you can profile in a real-world scenario. With that said, there are "relaxed" RB-tree variants which allow you to delay rebalancing operations.

Comment: When inserting a large number of sequential keys, if indeed you establish that regular rb tree operations are not good enough, I can think of two ways to maybe speed it up. One: if you know how many consecutive keys you're going to insert, you might be able to optimise the  rebalancing by postponing it until after all elements are inserted. Two: during such a multi-insertion, maintain a pointer to the previously inserted node to avoid having to search for it again.

Comment: @JimMischel - it seems the key is required to be sorted for eviction purposes so an unsorted container might not work well

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: The dictionary is indexed by key and holds a reference to the the linked list node. So eviction is easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can maintain a sorted std::deque

That should fit all your criterial and allow for period resizing (eviction)

Comment: A sorted deque would not allow O(log n) insertion.

Comment: @Ben it is unclear if key is time sequential and therefore all inserts would be front inserts

Comment: Only if key=timestamp.